# Add parameter to request using JavaScript

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, ce-1.9.0.1

Is there a way to add information to the post request which will be sent when I press the "save product" button? I have added some custom things to the product I need to transmit in order to process them (using the catalog_product_prepare_save event).
I have a dropdown menu next to a button, and when I press that button, I need to transmit the content of the dropdown via the request array so that I can receive the option selected in the observer I have registered.

Thanks a lot in advance

EDIT: I have a feeling there is something completely wrong about the way I'm approaching this, a nudge in the right direction would be much appreciated, I'm quite stuck atm.

Comment: why dont to go for event observer?.

Comment: @Manik well, I have an event observer, but with that, I can only get the php request data (obviously). The things I need to process though are on the page. My question now is how I can somehow put this data I got into the php request in order to handle it with an observer

Comment: can you please update the question with what data you want to get where it exist?

Comment: done, hope this helps

Comment: maybe I got you wrong, but shouldn't you already get it in the Post array if you named your select (as in name="myselect")?

Comment: -.- yes... I DID approach this from the wrong angle in a way too complicated manner. Well, thanks @JulienLachal :D If you write an answer within a few hours I'll accept yours (if you want the rep), otherwise I'll write it down myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's purely PHP-related I think, just name your select like this :

```
<select name="myselect">.....</select>
```

And you should be able to retrieve it like this

```
$this->getRequest()->getParam('myselect');
```